# turn columns into rows?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm working with some results from a database query in excel. Is there a way I can quickly turn two rows of data with many columns into two columns of data with many rows?

Comment: Good question, which I find useful.  But you should consider doing something about your poor Accept Rate. *(If you need incentive, you know you get +rep for Accepting an answer, right?)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [this page](http://kb.iu.edu/data/akwu.html). Shortly, you need to execute 'Paste Special' with 'Transpose' turned on.